# XAML container control for specific controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a custom control that has multiple children of a specific class.
For example, ToolBarTray in WPF can contain only ToolBar child.

```
 <ToolBarTray>
            <ToolBar>..</ToolBar>
            <ToolBar>..</ToolBar>
 </ToolBarTray>
```

This costraint on the type of children is enforced by the XAML synta.
How can I achieve the same results with two custom controls:

```
 <MyCustomControlA>
            <MyCustomControlB>..</MyCustomControlB>
            <MyCustomControlB>..</MyCustomControlB>
 </MyCustomControlA>
```

I tried to create a custom control extending ItemsControl, but there is no way to enforce any constraint in the XAML syntax.

Comment: "I tried to create a custom control extending ItemsControl, but there is no way to enforce any constraint in the XAML syntax" - there is method `GetContainerForItemOverride`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `ContentPropertyAttribute` and implement your custom control as bellow:

```
    public class MyCustomControlB : Control
    {

    }

    [ContentProperty("MyCustomControls")]
    public class MyCustomControlA : FrameworkElement
    {
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<MyCustomControlB> MyCustomControls { get; }

        .
        .
        .
    }
```

Comment: That's what I suggested, wasn't it?

Comment: Yep, I'm so sorry. I didn't see your answer when I post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the [ContentPropertyAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

That's that the `ToolBarTray` class uses:

```
[ContentProperty("ToolBars")]
public class ToolBarTray : FrameworkElement, IAddChild
...
```

The type of the `ToolBars` property is `Collection<ToolBar>`.